# ThreeJS VRMLLoader giving "invalid color" error

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, vrml

I am having trouble with the VRMLLoader in ThreeJS,
I load the file like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
loader.load( 'testscan.wrl', function ( object ) {
    object.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add( object );
    //console.log(object)
    //console.log("done loading");
} );
```

and I keep getting the following warning:

```
VRMLLoader.js:406 ["color", "Color"]
    parseProperty @ VRMLLoader.js:406
    getTree @ VRMLLoader.js:571
    parseV2 @ VRMLLoader.js:1048
    parse @ VRMLLoader.js:1098
    (anonymous) @ VRMLLoader.js:36
    (anonymous) @ three.min.js:618
VRMLLoader.js:407 Invalid color format detected for color
    parseProperty @ VRMLLoader.js:407
    getTree @ VRMLLoader.js:571
    parseV2 @ VRMLLoader.js:1048
    parse @ VRMLLoader.js:1098
    (anonymous) @ VRMLLoader.js:36
    (anonymous) @ three.min.js:618
VRMLLoader.js:406 ["color"]
    parseProperty @ VRMLLoader.js:406
    getTree @ VRMLLoader.js:571
    parseV2 @ VRMLLoader.js:1048
    parse @ VRMLLoader.js:1098
    (anonymous) @ VRMLLoader.js:36
    (anonymous) @ three.min.js:618
VRMLLoader.js:407 Invalid color format detected for color
```

but the model doesn't appear in the Scene at all when its done loading.
not even without its color

the colors in the .wrl file are defined so:

```
geomery IndexedFaceSet
{   
    ... 
    color Color
    {
        color
        [
            0.196078 0.0823529 0.130846,
            ...
            0.152271 0.188965 0.317428
        ]
    }
...
}
```

any help would be appreciated

The .wrl file i'm trying to load:
[link](https://joelscloudspace.blaucloud.de/index.php/s/Ursd8PzJ10P5dc2)